# EM Algorithm not working

Tags: statistics, processing, expectation-maximization

I am trying to implement a simple EM algorithm. So far, it seems to be working well except for the small problem that variances quickly shrink to zero, converging around the mean of the data. (If I do not update the variances, it will converge to the mean completely fine!)

As far as I can tell, this is due to "weighting" the points close to the centre too heavily - hence making the algorithm lower the variance and shrink to zero. When I change the formula from [image: First] to [image: Second] the algorithm works much better (apart from slightly overestimating variance, which is to be expected). Is this a problem with my code?

```
class DataPoint {
  int nDims; // Number of dimensions
  float[] data;
  DataPoint(int n) {nDims = n; data = new float[n];}
  DataPoint(float[] d) {nDims = d.length; data = d;}
}

float sum(float[] d) {float ret = 0; for (int i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {ret += d[i];} return ret;}
float[] sub(float[] f, float[] u) {float[] ret = new float[f.length]; for (int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i) {ret[i] = f[i] - u[i];} return ret;}
float distSq(float[] d) {float ret = 0; for (int i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {ret += d[i]*d[i];} return ret;}
float distSq(float[][] d) {float ret = 0; for (int i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {ret += distSq(d[i]);} return ret;}

float det(float[][] mat) {
  if (mat.length == 2 && mat[0].length == 2) {
    float det = (mat[0][0] * mat[1][1]) - (mat[0][1] * mat[1][0]);
    return det;
  }
  throw new RuntimeException("Det has to be 2x2");
}

float[][] inverse(float[][] mat) {
  if (mat.length == 2 && mat[0].length == 2) {
    float det = mat[0][0] * mat[1][1] - mat[0][1] * mat[1][0];
    float[][] ret = {{mat[1][1]/det, -mat[0][1]/det}, {-mat[1][0]/det, mat[0][0]/det}};
    return ret;
  }
  throw new RuntimeException("Inverse has to be 2x2");

}

class GMM {
  int number;
  int dims;
  float[] weights;
  float[][] means;
  float[][][] covariances;
  float[][][] invCov;


  GMM(int gNo, int noDimensions) {
    number = gNo;
    dims = noDimensions;
    weights = new float[gNo];
    means = new float[gNo][noDimensions];
    covariances = new float[gNo][noDimensions][noDimensions];
    invCov      = new float[gNo][noDimensions][noDimensions];

    // Initialise to random values.
    for (int i = 0; i < gNo; ++i) {
      weights[i] = random(0, 1);
      for (int j = 0; j < noDimensions; ++j) {
        means[i][j] = random(-100,100);
        covariances[i][j][j] = 100;
        invCov[i] = inverse(covariances[i]);
      }
    }
    normaliseWeights();
  }

  float[][] EStep(DataPoint[] data) {
    // For each data point, return probablility of each gaussian having generated it
    // Arguments: n-dimensional data
    float[][] ret = new float[number][data.length];

    for (int Gauss = 0; Gauss < number; ++Gauss) {
      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        ret[Gauss][i] = calculateProbabilityFast(data[i], Gauss);
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }

  void MStep(DataPoint[] data, float[][] dataProbabilities) {
    for (int Gauss = 0; Gauss < number; ++Gauss) {
      means[Gauss] = new float[data[0].nDims]; // Reset dims to zero
      float probSum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < dataProbabilities[Gauss].length; ++i) {
        probSum += dataProbabilities[Gauss][i];
        for (int j = 0; j < means[Gauss].length; ++j) {
          means[Gauss][j] += data[i].data[j] * dataProbabilities[Gauss][i];
        }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < means[Gauss].length; ++i) {
        means[Gauss][i] /= probSum; // Normalise
      }
      // Means[Gauss] has been updated

      // Now for covariance.... :x
      covariances[Gauss] = new float[data[0].nDims][data[0].nDims];
      for (int m = 0; m < data[0].nDims; ++m) {
        for (int n = 0; n < data[0].nDims; ++n) {
          for (int i = 0; i < dataProbabilities[Gauss].length; ++i) {
            covariances[Gauss][m][n] += (data[i].data[m]-means[Gauss][m])*(data[i].data[n]-means[Gauss][n])*dataProbabilities[Gauss][i];
          }
        }
      }
      // Created a triangular matrix, normalise and then update other half too.
      for (int m = 0; m < data[0].nDims; ++m) {
        for (int n = 0; n < data[0].nDims; ++n) {
          covariances[Gauss][m][n] /= probSum;
        }
      }
      // Update inverses
      invCov[Gauss] = inverse(covariances[Gauss]);
      weights[Gauss] = probSum;
    }
    normaliseWeights();
  }

  float calculateProbabilityFast(DataPoint x, int Gauss) {
    float ret = pow(TWO_PI, dims/2.0)*sqrt(det(covariances[Gauss]));
    float exponent = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.nDims; ++i) {
      float temp = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < x.nDims; ++j) {
        temp += (x.data[j] - means[Gauss][j])*invCov[Gauss][i][j];
      }
      exponent += temp*(x.data[i] - means[Gauss][i]);
    }
    exponent = exp(-0.5*exponent);
    // ==================================================================
    // If I change this line HERE to -0.3*exponent, everything works fine
    // ==================================================================
    //print(exponent); print(","); println(ret);
    return exponent/ret;
  }



  void normaliseWeights() {
    float sum = sum(weights);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {weights[i] /= sum;}
  }

  void display() {
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
      //strokeWeight(weights[i]*100);
      strokeWeight(5);
      stroke(color(255, 0, 0));
      point(means[i][0], means[i][1]);
      noFill();
      strokeWeight(1.5);
      ellipse(means[i][0], means[i][1], (covariances[i][0][0]), (covariances[i][1][1]));
      ellipse(means[i][0], means[i][1], (covariances[i][0][0]*2), (covariances[i][1][1]*2));
      fill(0);
    }
  }
}

DataPoint[] data;

final int size = 10000;

GMM MixModel;

void setup() {
  // Hidden gaussians
  size(800,600);
  MixModel = new GMM(1, 2); // 1 gaussians, 2 dimensions.
  data = new DataPoint[size];
  int gNo = 1;
  float gxMeans[] = new float[gNo];
  float gxVars[]  = new float[gNo];
  float gyMeans[] = new float[gNo];
  float gyVars[]  = new float[gNo];
  float covars[]  = new float[gNo];
  for (int i = 0; i < gNo; ++i) {
    gxMeans[i] = random(-100, 100);
    gxVars[i] =  random(5, 40);
    gyMeans[i] = random(-100, 100);
    gyVars[i] =  random(5, 40); // Actually std. devs!! 
    covars[i] = 0;//random(-1, 1);
    println("Vars: " + str(pow(gxVars[i], 2)) + ", " + str(pow(gyVars[i], 2)));
    println("Covar: " + str(covars[i]));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    int gauss = (int)random(gNo);
    data[i] = new DataPoint(2);
    data[i].data[0] = randomGaussian()*gxVars[gauss] + gxMeans[gauss];
    data[i].data[1] = (randomGaussian()*gyVars[gauss])*(1-abs(covars[gauss]))+(gyVars[gauss]*covars[gauss]*(data[i].data[0]-gxMeans[gauss])/gxVars[gauss]) + gyMeans[gauss];
  }


  frameRate(5); // Let's see what's happening!
}


void draw() {
  translate(width/2, height/2); // set 0,0 at centre
  background(color(255, 255, 255));
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(1);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    point(data[i].data[0], data[i].data[1]);
  }
  MixModel.display();
  float[][] dataProbs = MixModel.EStep(data);
  MixModel.MStep(data, dataProbs);
  print(MixModel.covariances[0][0][0]); print(", ");
  println(MixModel.covariances[0][1][1]);
}
```

**EDIT:** Complete, minimal working example. The variance still converges to 0, so this suggests perhaps I'm doing something wrong with the algorithm?

```
import random, statistics, math

hiddenMu = random.uniform(-100, 100)
hiddenVar = random.uniform(10, 30)
dataLen = 10000

data = [random.gauss(hiddenMu, hiddenVar) for i in range(dataLen)]

hiddenVar **= 2 # Make it the actual variance rather than std. dev.

print("Variance: " + str(hiddenVar) + ", actual: " + str(statistics.variance(data)))
print("Mean    : " + str(hiddenMu ) + ", actual: " + str(statistics.mean    (data)))

guessMu = random.uniform(-100, 100)
guessVar = 100

print("Initial mu guess:  " + str(guessMu))
print("Initial var guess: " + str(guessVar))

# perform iterations

numIters = 100

for i in range(numIters):

    dataProbs = [math.exp(-0.5*((i-guessMu)**2)/guessVar)/((2*math.pi*guessVar)**0.5) for i in data]

    guessMu = sum(map(lambda x: x[0]*x[1], zip(dataProbs, data)))/sum(dataProbs)
    guessVar = sum(map(lambda x: x[0]*((x[1]-guessMu)**2), zip(dataProbs, data)))/sum(dataProbs)

    print(str(i) + " mu guess:  " + str(guessMu))
    print(str(i) + " var guess: " + str(guessVar))
    print()
```

**EDIT 2**: Could I need something like Bessel's correction? (multiply the result by n/(n-1)). If so, how would I go about doing this when the sum of the probabilities themselves may be less than one?

Comment: This question is probably too broad for Stack Overflow. Have you tried [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected? Can you post a smaller [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Of course I've tried debugging it, I'm not *trying* to waste people's time :3
As for which line it is, I'm not sure. I know the program is underestimating the variance, I'm going to try and post a 1D example in Python to see if the same thing happens.

Comment: What is the model to which you are applying EM?

Comment: @RobertDodier Jut a simple normal distribution, as shown in the code.

Comment: @TheAbelo2 Then what is the point of the EM algorithm? EM is applied when there are hidden or latent variables -- estimating the missing variables in the E step and then maximizing the likelihood for free parameters in the M step. When there are no missing variables, there is just one M step and you're done. Instead of trying to apply EM to a problem that doesn't call for it, why not work on one that does, e.g. Gaussian mixture estimation with 2 components. By that way, you mention "as shown in the code", but I think it's unreasonable to expect others to puzzle it out -- better to explain it.

Comment: @RobertDodier I was simply trying to figure out how to make it work, I'm not going to be using the EM algorithm only where I know the distribution of data... but I do need to make sure it will work before I apply it to other problems.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same problem, I now understand the conditional assigning of points to separate Gaussians in a GMM. You might see this with NaNs showing up in your programs, such as in question [EM algorithm code is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979808/em-algorithm-code-is-not-working?rq=1)

Rather than assigning each point the probability of belonging to the Gaussian with the formula listed above, you need to assign that probability and then **normalise** over all Gaussians listed - which means that when a point can be assigned to a Gaussian, it becomes completely assigned if that Gaussian is the only one that could have generated it - i.e. the probability becomes 1, even if it was originally only a very small chance of having come from that distribution.